# How to pass JWT via Header and retrieve data through Server Side Views in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, jwt, express-jwt

Backend: Sails.js

I have already implemented JSON Web Token for the REST API, where all AJAX requests from the front-end to the actions of various controllers return data `res.json(data);` only if it receives a correct JWT via Authorization Header. It works as expected.

Now, i have created a view using EJS with `<%= name =>`, now a controller has the details `res.view('/home', {name: "Bill"} );` and configured the routes to point to the respective controller too.

How do i retrieve "name" from the controller by authenticating with an already issued JWT (stored in localStorage) from a Server Side View with the attribute `<%= name =>`

Thanks.

CODE:

views/index.ejs

```
<%= name =>
```

api/controllers/UsersController.js

```
info: function(req, res) {

var userId = req.token;

Users.findOne(userId).exec(function(err, profile) {
    if(err) {
    res.json(err);
    } else {
       res.view('index',{
        name: profile.name,
    });
    }
});        
},
```

api/policies/tokenAuth.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var token;

  if (req.headers && req.headers.authorization) {
    var parts = req.headers.authorization.split(' ');
    if (parts.length == 2) {
      var scheme = parts[0],
        credentials = parts[1];

      if (/^Bearer$/i.test(scheme)) {
        token = credentials;
      }
    } else {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'Format is Authorization: Bearer [token]'});
    }
  } else if (req.param('token')) {
    token = req.param('token');
    delete req.query.token;
  } else {
    return res.json(401, {err: 'No Authorization header was found'});
  }

  sailsTokenAuth.verifyToken(token, function(err, token) {
    if (err) return res.json(401, {err: 'Please Logout and Login again!'});

    req.token = token;

    next();
  });
};
```

api/services/sailsTokenAuth.js

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports.issueToken = function(payload) {
  var token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || "xxxxxxx");
  return token;
};

module.exports.verifyToken = function(token, verified) {
  return jwt.verify(token, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET || "xxxxxxx", {}, verified);
};
```

config/routes.js

```
module.exports.routes = {
    '/': {
        controller: 'UsersController',
        action: 'info'
      },
};
```

**SOLUTION:**

To use JWT as an authenticating factor from client browser to server, either localStorage or session cookie can be used. I have finally narrowed it down to using the cookie since due to easier implementation in the server.

After authenticating the user, store the JWT in the clients browser,

```
res.cookie('jwttoken', sailsTokenAuth.issueToken(profile.name));
```

Then it can be retrieved using `req.cookies.jwttoken` and verify it through a service (jwt.verify) to give access to requested information via `res.json` or `res.view`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't see any of your code, as not provided, but lets say that you set up a custom policy **api/policies/jwt.js** etc, and in there you check the JWTToken on each request. Something like (ignoring any error handling for simplicity):

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    var token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    var payload = jwt.decode(token, config.TOKEN_SECRET);
    req.userId = payload.sub;
    next();
};
```

Notice how I have appended the userId onto the **req** object (**req.userId = payload.sub;**). That means in your **controller**, you will have access to the **userId** (or in your case whatever id you are using to identify your logged in user etc), as you can simply reference it from the incoming **req** object.

Obviously your implementation of the JWT policy may vary, but just customize it to something like above. If you actually kept the **name** in the jwt token itself (cannot see your implementation) then simply append this to the req object (no model lookup needed).

Once you have the needed **name**, pass that to your view (as you are currently doing with hardcoded value *Bill* above.

**Update based on updated question**

So based on your comment and updated question, you have managed to extract the profile information from JWT token, and get required profile info from a model lookup. You are now unable to get that name presented on the EJS view.

So you could achieve this something like:

Controller:

```
res.view('index', {
        name: profile.name
    }
```

**Notice I removed the comma after profile.name  ;)**

**config/views.js** should be set to "ejs" if that is the templating engine you are using.

The rest looks good. At least, consistent with what I would have expected.

Your best bet is to either explicitly use a debugger, or at least console.log statements right up to point just before the controller.info method returns, and ensure the profile.name is set as expected. If you get that far, then you'll know that the problem is with the routing to view somehow.

You could try creating a subfolder under views and also rename the view file (index is slightly special..). Do something like **views/xxx/yyy.ejs**

Also temporarily comment out your controller.info method, and replace it with something really simple like:

```
res.view('xxx/yyy', {
            name: 'bob'
        });
```

**Further update based on further user feedback**

From your last comment, your question is gradually evolving...

What I think you are now saying is that the Sails code is all working, and proven working using Postman. But failing when using a web browser client because your client code isn't passing the correct Token information in the http header.

If that is the case, you'll need create an Interceptor on the Client that applies the header information programmatically.

Eg. (just a snippet taken from out of an Angular factory authInterceptor, but nothing angular specific shown here):

```
 request: function (config) {
      var token = authToken.getToken();

      if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
      }

      return config;
    },
```

Above, on request, the JWT is retrieved from local storage (which you say you have working), and if the token exists, then the http headers information is updated with an authorization header of the form '**Bearer token**'.

I haven't looked at your repo, and to be honest I do feel I have given you ALOT of information already. Based on what I have provided, and perhaps a little more googling / testing you should be able to get a working solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have added code samples with the question.

Like you said, i have already implemented userId into the JWT secret and works fine for REST API Calls. Like the Client/Front-end requests information with an Authorization Header with JWT Token, it is then received in the Back-end (Controller/Action) using `req.token` which translates to the userID for processing the requested information. 

But what i am confused is with how to retrieve the same information from Server Side Views.

Comment: What i am actually trying to do:

1. Login View:
Get userId and password -> Generate JWT -> Store it in User Browser's localStorage

2. Redirect to Profile View
(Only users with Valid JWT can access it)

While accessing using AJAX calls, it works as expected i can get information using 'res.json' but i would like to make it work using 'res.view' instead using Server Side Views without using AJAX requests since those *.ejs files are already residing in the server.

Comment: I have created a repo: https://github.com/vijayrajasekaran/sails-auth-jwt

I am able to get the name: bob in the view with JWT disabled with the controller. It also works with JWT enabled when i pass a REST API call with Authorization Header (JWT Token)

But unable to understand, how do i make a user authenticated after a successful login and let him browse multiple views protected by JWT since i am not sending the Authorization header as REST API calls to get the requested info.

When the view is directly visited using localhost/profile, it displays "No authorization header".

Comment: Scenerio (for the Repository i added in GitHub):

1. User has the JWT in his Browser's localStorage
2. When he visits, http://localhost:1337/profile
3. He should get a page rendered with "name: smith'..

This works fine when doing REST API calls with Postman REST Client/jQuery AJAX calls with Authorization Header: Bearer 'token'

Comment: @VijayRajasekaran - updated my answer - note I haven't had time to look at your repo. Be grateful if you could upvote / mark my answer as correct if you found the information helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to help me out. Your answer was really helpful. To use JWT as an authenticating factor from client browser to server, either localStorage or session cookie can be used. I have finally narrowed it down to using the cookie since due to easier implementation in the server.

Comment: @VijayRajasekaran - happy to have helped, and great to see you using JWT. Yeah, for the client side, it is often better to lean on a library that does all the heavy lifting. for example satellizer for angular makes this a breeze - https://www.npmjs.com/package/satellizer.  Please would you mark my answer as the correct answer if you felt it was really helpful :D  and best of luck with your project work.

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you so much. :)